# Spring MVC from 2.5 to 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We are migrating our web application from Spring 2.5 to Spring 3.0.5. Looks like all the Controller classes (the classes in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc package: BaseCommandController, AbstractCommandController, SimpleFormController, etc) have been deprecated. We used those classes heavily in our application. These classes have been replaced by @Controller annotation instead.

I have a few questions regarding Spring 3.0.x Controller configuration...

1. We used the following XML to create a Controller bean in Spring 2.5. If <context:component-scan> is used instead to create the Controller beans, then how do I wire-in the dependencies? If possible I would like to avoid Auto-Wiring.

```
<bean id="photosetViewController" class="com.xyz.web.PhotosetViewController"
    p:photosetManager-ref="photosetManager"
    p:photoManager-ref="photoManager" />
```

1. We have created 3 Interceptors. We use SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to map these Interceptors to different request URLs and also to map URLs to Controllers. How do we achieve the same in Spring 3.0.x?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />      
       <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
               <ref bean="httpRedirectInterceptor"/>
               <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
           </list>
       </property>      
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>             
                /abc.html=abcLookupController
                /photoupload.html=photoUploadController
          </value>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true" />      
       <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
               <ref bean="httpRedirectInterceptor"/>
               <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
               <ref bean="userMenuInterceptor" />
           </list>
       </property>      
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /index.html=homepageController
                /success.html=simpleController
            </value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

1. In case of SimpleFormControllers we used different methods like initBinder, referenceData, formBackingObject. We also used command objects and validation classes. How do we achieve the same in Spring 3.0.x?

```
<bean id="photosetAddController" class="com.xyz.web.PhotosetAddController"
    p:photosetManager-ref="photosetManager"
    p:photosetTypeManager-ref="photosetTypeManager"
    p:stateManager-ref="stateManager" >
    <property name="validator">
    <bean class="com.xyz.form.PhotosetAddValidator" />
    </property>
    <property name="formView" value="photosetadd" />
    <property name="successView" value="redirect:/photoset" /> 
</bean>
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please ask separate questions separately. They are related, sure, but they can also be better answered independently.

Comment: All of the above will work just fine in Spring 3 (deprecated != removed). It just means there's now a better way of doing these things, but you don't need to do it all in one go.

Comment: skaffman, I heard a lecture from Arjen Poutsma(SpringSource developer)  that the deprecated features will be removed in future versions. Though I knew my app would be supported in Spring 3.0, I felt we should make those changes now rather than later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As skaffman noted - your code will work fine without any modifications. I'll answer your questions in short:

1. You can use `@Resource(name="beanName")` for name-based injection. But autowiring is also a good option. Either `@Autowired`, or `@javax.inject.Inject`. Note that you can use `@Qualifier("name")` to differentiate between beans with the same interface/base class. You can even use the `javax.inject` qualifiers (read about all these in the docs)
2. interceptor mappings can stay the same
3. There is `@InitBinder`, which denotes the initBinder method. I can't tell about the other.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Bozho! Though the deprecated features are supported, they will be removed in future versions according to Arjen Poutsma.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the @Resource annotation. Will use that with the combination of @Autowired. What would be the names of the Controller beans if they are initialized through <context:component-scan> rather than explicit bean declarations like <bean id="abc" class="abcLookupController"? Also if the RequestMapping is in the controller class itself, what should be in the mappings property of SimpleUrlHandlerMapping?

Comment: yes, they are declared only through `@Controller` and component-scan. About the mappings - just remove the url mappings from the handler and retain only the interceptors.

Comment: Many thanks, Bozho! Probably I will use the mvc:interceptors tag. That answers the first two questions. I will figure out how to get the SimpleFormController functionality using the annotations later.

Comment: `<mvc:interceptors>` is nice, but I'm actually using your way (using the handler), because the `<mvc:` has some issues that appeared in my case. Have this in mind.

Comment: The problem is, we have three interceptors, which we apply conditionally to different controllers. SimpleUrlHandlerMapping allowed us to do this. But with mappings property removed, I wouldn't be able to map different interceptors to different controllers. What issues did you face with mvc:interceptors tag?

Comment: I don't remember actually what exactly were the issues. Btw, how did you handle conditiona interceptors? The mapping property shouldn't do that, I think.

Comment: I shouldn't have said conditional interceptors. I meant different interceptors applied to different URLs (hence different controllers). As you can see in my first post above, httpRedirectInterceptor and loginInterceptor were applied to abc.html and photoupload.html. However httpRedirectInterceptor, loginInterceptor and userMenuInterceptor are applied to index.html and success.html.

Comment: Now that mappings are done within the controller class using @RequestMapping annotations, I was thinking about using mvc:interceptors tag to map interceptors to URLs.